# Custom facebook like message on users page

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook app that is built in PHP and have added a Facebook like button, which works quite well, however, the like button links to the page and i would like to know if it is possible to link to certain elements on the page. As an example, i have various coupons displayed and when a user clicks the like button on a certain coupon, i would like the message on the users page to say what coupon was liked and from what app, i.e. discount coupon from myAppName. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Look at the [Like button documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), which specifies how to use Open Graph tags to customize the messages.

Basically, you'll need to have a different url for each coupon, which will contain OG tags for that coupon. You can use the [debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to test this.

Then set the Like button URLs in your homepage (or wherever) to your coupon urls.

Comment: my coupons are called using jquery and ajax, so therefore don't have a set url. They are then placed into the page which has the header and footer called from another script.

Comment: you'll need a unique URL for each coupon in order to set up the meta tags correctly

Comment: ok, thanks for the info, will play about to see if i can find a solution.

Comment: This url can be very simple: just a `<html><head> (COUPON OG TAGS) <script>location = 'REDIRECT_URL';</script></head></html>`